# How to provide make file argument to substitute in ifdef condition

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I know its simple but I'm missing something here.

I want to build my code in host that is x86. When I give just `make` it builds for the arm.

I'm wondering how to make this build to my host? I set the variable `LOCAL_BUILD:=host` and the gave `make` host I got the error.

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'host'.  Stop.
```

**common.makefile, this how it looks like.**

```
DEFAULT: all

# Generic platform code

LOCAL_BUILD:=host

ifdef LOCAL_BUILD
include $(PLATFORM)/scripts/x86.makefile
else
include $(PLATFORM)/scripts/arm.makefile
endif

all:
ifndef  LOCAL_BUILD
    TOP=$(TOP)/scripts/see.sh
endif
    mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(MAKE) imag
```

EDIT:
by default it builds for the arm, I mean just `make` from dir builds for arm.

How to substitute the ifdef variable from make argument?

Any help very appreciated thanks.

Comment: "I set the variable LOCAL_BUILD:=host". Your `common.makefile` does not
show that. [mcve] needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to substitute the ifdef variable from make argument?

[Variables assigned to in `make` command line override assignments in the makefile](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Overriding), e.g.:

```
$ cat Makefile
LOCAL_BUILD := anything
$(info LOCAL_BUILD=${LOCAL_BUILD})

$ make
LOCAL_BUILD=anything
make: *** No targets.  Stop.

$ make LOCAL_BUILD=host
LOCAL_BUILD=host
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```

Comment: Actually `make LOCAL_BUILD=host`, substituted the value. I can able to build now, thanks. My mistake was `make host`. I was in an impression that I can pass the value of the variable.